# Why is my Minecraft server generating mod folders?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Running a vanilla MC server in Debian, and I'm having an issue where the server seems to be generating nested /mod folders with redundant data, is this normal?

The full file path to the current deepest iteration is:

```
/home/appdata/Minecraft/My_Server/mods/mods/mods/mods/mods/mods/mods/mods/mods/mods/mods/mods/mods/mods/mods/mods
```

What's going on here? This creates a drastic increase in storage use and looks sloppy. Is there a way to organize it more effectively?

Update: backed up the server, deleted the whole /mods root folder, and on boot the log posts this:

```
Running as uid=1003 gid=100 with /data as 'drwxrwxr-x    6 1003     100           4096 Aug 21 08:06 /data'
Checking version information.
Checking type information.
server.properties already created, skipping
Checking for JSON files.
Copying any mods over...
update:mods/banned-ips.json:Last Modified 2019/08/20-14:54:51
```

And proceeds to duplicate all files into the newly created /mods folder.

Comment: Are you sure it's a vanilla executable and not forge, spigot or similar?

Comment: I generated a new docker container as a test, and the exact same thing is happening in the fresh test server.

Comment: With what command  do you start the server? Are there any non-empty JSON files, except ops and whitelist?

Comment: I use a gui that sends a /start command.

usercache.json seems to be the only .json containing data.

Comment: strange.. seems your GUI is causing this. Try starting the server directly and see what happens without docker

Comment: I upvoted this just because it's funny. Nice path you have there, `…/mods/mods/mods/mods/mods/…` I can only assume that his is something that's supposed to move mods out of it, which is strange, because it doesn't do it in Singleplayer and using a world without mods that previously had mods is strongly discouraged. What data is there actually in these `mods` folders?

Comment: Just resolved the issue, check out my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from the creator of the docker I'm using.

> You'll either need to disable the mounts of /config and /mods or at
>   least bind them to different host paths than you have configured for
>   /data
>
> The /mods and /config are optional to let you manually populate a
>   shared directory/volume each with your common configurations and those
>   get copied over to the container's /data directory...so it's quite
>   normal to either not attach those paths or point them at empty
>   directories.